# How to assign accounts in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to try to develope my lambda-function in terraform. Since the function is a cross account costoverview, how can I assume in terraform multiple accounts?

So this is a codesnippet from my `main.tf`

```
#ROLE FOR ACCOUNT A COST REPORT
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_costoverview" {
  name                  = "role_costoverview"
  description           = "default cross report role"
  assume_role_policy    = "${file("policy_account_a.json")}"
}


#ROLE FOR ACCOUNT B COST REPORT                      
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_costoverview" {
  name                  = "role_costoverview"
  description           = "assume_role cross report role"
  assume_role_policy    = "${file("policy_account_b.json")}"
}
```

So how can I write the code that Terraform recognize, there are two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you have TWO different AWS accounts, right?
I do also work with different AWS accounts, and each time I have to set the environment variable for required account.
So, I have small script (`script.sh`) with account details:

```
export AWS_REGION="region-where-I-want-to-apply"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export TF_VAR_region="${AWS_REGION}"
export TF_VAR_public_key='ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXX-ssh-key'

export TF_VAR_access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
export TF_VAR_secret_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

The AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are from one account and for another account you can create another file.
I just have to `source` this script before switching to another account.
`$source /script/path/script.sh`